# Windows equivalent of Unix "find" command?

Tags: windows, cmd, find

I'd like to be able to search files on a Windows machine using the command line instead of the GUI interface. For example, on Linux, I use:

find . -name "*.c" -exec grep -Hn "sqlcommand" {} \;

Is there something similar with Windows?

Comment: I never used Windows seriously (except for looking some map in hotels), but I heard that Windows had some [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) which might be more easy to use than the old DOS command line. You might use Windows without using a DOS command line.

Comment: This should be asked at http://superuser.com.

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285148/windows-equivalent-for-unix-find-command-to-search-multiple-file-types

Comment: @user3772839: I know it has been a while, but I recently found something that you might "find" interesting ;-). Please see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28332218/577765).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long time working with Unix systems I had to make some scripts on Windows.
For serious scripting Powershell is the tool you should use.
You can search Internet with keywords like `powershell find string in file`,
or other combinations and you find a lot of information.
That's the problem, a simple oneliner like

```
get-childitem C:\yourdir -include *.c -recursive |Select-String -pattern sqlcommand
```

won't help you much. You need to find the PowerShell IDE, learn the different syntax and try to love / accept that new stuff.

Prepare for a study with PowerShell when you want to do these things more often, or try to get a Unix-like environment on your windows (cygwin, or better git for windows)

Answer (score 4):

**NEW AND IMPROVED ANSWER**

I recently stumbled upon a built-in command that is rather similar to `find` in Unix:

[ForFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles)

Basic syntax is:

```
forfiles [/p <Path>] [/m <SearchMask>] [/s] [/c <Command>] [/d [{+|-}][{<Date>|<Days>}]]
```

There are several variables to use when constructing the command to execute per each file (via the `/c` switch):

- `@FILE`   File name.
- `@FNAME`  File name without extension.
- `@EXT`    File name extension.
- `@PATH`   Full path of the file.
- `@RELPATH`    Relative path of the file.
- `@ISDIR`  Evaluates to TRUE if a file type is a directory. Otherwise, this variable evaluates to FALSE.
- `@FSIZE`  File size, in bytes.
- `@FDATE`  Last modified date stamp on the file.
- `@FTIME`  Last modified time stamp on the file.

It looks like you would use the command like this:

```
FORFILES /m *.cs /c FINDSTR /I /N /C:"sqlcommand" @FILE
```

I'm not sure how long this command has been around, but the earliest reference I could find in the documentation is from 2008-09-02:

https://web.archive.org/web/20080902221744/http://technet.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx

and that page states that it was last updated on "April 25, 2007". The documentation is filed under "Windows Server" so it likely started there and was added to the desktop OSes starting with Windows Vista, I believe. I did check Windows XP and didn't see it there, though it is on Windows 10.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This requires a combination of two DOS commands:

- `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]`

  and
- `DIR /B /O:N /W *.c` (this is the `'command'` noted in the `FOR` command above)

Create a CMD script as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F %%B IN ('DIR /B /O:N /W *.cs') DO (
    findstr /I /N /C:"sqlcommand" %%B
)
```

---

**OR**, just use the `find` command found in this set of Unix command ports:

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

or

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/

(both links should be the same project)